# How to create a custom marker with icon and buttons with Android map v2

Tags: android, google-maps

Now I have standart marker with text like this: [standart marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FU8M.png)

How create custom marker with icon and buttons close and call, somethig like this

[custom marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De1Sy.png)

Now I have this code:

```
private void addMarker(Company company) {
    if(_map != null) {
        LatLng place = new LatLng(company.Latitude, company.Longitude);
        _map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(place)
            .title(company.Name)
            .snippet(String.format("%s %s", company.Phone, company.Address))
            .draggable(false)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
            .flat(true));
        _map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place, 12));
    }
}
```

Comment: read the documenation....https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image    flollow this code   private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
  private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(MELBOURNE)
                            .title("Melbourne")
                            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));

Comment: But how add buttons?

Comment: add button... for this code..... // Create an Icon object for the marker to use
IconFactory iconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
Drawable iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.music_15);
Icon icon = iconFactory.fromDrawable(iconDrawable);

// Add the marker to the map
mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(-33.85699436, 151.21510684))
        .icon(icon));